# How can acces a function from another fragment using viewmodel

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewmodel

I have a function in one of my fragment which checks if the cardview have changed the colors, now i want to access that function using the view model architecture to another fragment i know i have to use the viewmodel in order to access that but am confused how can i perform that,

**here is my function from fragment A**

```
public boolean checkIthestudentiscleared()
    {


        //get the color of the cardview and check which color is it if #2b434f then he /she is cleared
        int background_colorbursar = cardViewbusar.getCardBackgroundColor ().getDefaultColor ();
        int background_colorsnal = cardView.getCardBackgroundColor ().getDefaultColor ();
        int background_colorsuahab = cardViewsuahub.getCardBackgroundColor ().getDefaultColor ();
        int background_colorsports = cardViewsports.getCardBackgroundColor ().getDefaultColor ();
        int background_colorcict = cardViewcict.getCardBackgroundColor ().getDefaultColor ();
        int background_colorict_service = cardViewitcservices.getCardBackgroundColor ().getDefaultColor ();
        int background_coloreudtech = cardViewedutech.getCardBackgroundColor ().getDefaultColor ();
        int background_coloritcb = cardViewitcb.getCardBackgroundColor ().getDefaultColor ();


                if(background_colorbursar == Color.parseColor ("#ffffff") || background_colorcict == Color.parseColor ("#ffffff")
                || background_colorict_service == Color.parseColor ("#ffffff") || background_coloritcb == Color.parseColor ("#ffffff")
                || background_colorsnal == Color.parseColor ("#ffffff")  || background_coloreudtech == Color.parseColor ("#ffffff")  ||
                background_colorsuahab == Color.parseColor ("#ffffff") || background_colorsports == Color.parseColor ("#ffffff")){


                    Toast.makeText (getContext (), "Your not Cleared can't create the Clearance Report!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();

                    return false;

        }

                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText (getContext (), "The dean Has Approved your Clearance!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();
                    checkClearanceStatusViewModel.setValue ();
                    return true;



                }



    }
```

**This is my viewmodal class**

```
public class CheckClearanceStatusViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {



    public CheckClearanceStatusViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super (application);
    }







}
```

**have just tried doing that but am missing logic i want to be able to check the validity of that function from other fragment**

**on my fragment which has the fucntion**

```
 public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated (view, savedInstanceState);
        //init the viewmodel
        checkClearanceStatusViewModel = new ViewModelProvider (this).get (CheckClearanceStatusViewModel.class);
        checkClearanceStatusViewModel.getValue ().observe (getActivity (), new Observer<Boolean> () {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(Boolean aBoolean) {
                //logic here



            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**In the fragment where you want to check the validity, add the following code**

```
viewModel.getValue().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(Boolean value) {
             //your logic here
            }
        });
```

Comment: thanks i have that too but the logic is the one i need i have added it there so you can see it

Comment: So have you found the answer ?

Comment: no i have not the logic is what confuses me there what to write on the onChanged

Comment: the logic is what am missing